# How do I Stretch ring of vertices?

Tags: mesh, vertices, axis

I'm trying to fatten up the vertices outward that are in a circle, but I want to maintain its position and angle how do I do it?[image]

Comment: you can scale along the lines indicated by using 'S Shift-Z Shift-Z'.  Doubling the Z means to use the local axis and using shift means using the other two axis.  But those vertices lie on a tilted plane, just scaling with 'S' should work.  If you only want to do it in the direction of the arrows and not expand the loop on the other axis, try 'Sxx' or 'Syy' to see which one is the appropriate axis.  The axis that get drawn by the scale command will show you.

Comment: So hitting S Shift-Z Shift-Z causes my tiled vertices to became widen but vertical over time. The S key works fine, but the Sxx, causes it to be horizontal over time while Syy seems ok.